# mysql return multi level array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I'm working with three MySQL tables that are related in a PHP application. There are tests which have many questions, and the questions have many answers. What I would like to do is loop through the data as follows:

```
foreach($tests as $test)
{
    echo $test->testName;

    foreach($test->questions as $question)
    {
        echo $question->questionText;

        foreach($question->answers as $answer)
        {
            echo $answer->answerText;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is what the MySQL query and PHP code would be to loop through it in this manner?

**edit** MySQL can't return arrays like this, what I should have said is what would the MySQL + PHP code look like.

For clarity, the tables are tests, questions and answers. The questions table contains a test_id column, and the answers contains a question_id

Thanks!

The structure I'm looking to get back would be something along the lines of:

```
array(
    'testName' = 'Test name string',
    'questions' = array(
        array(
            'questionId' = 1,
            'questionText' = 'Question string',
            'answers' = array(
                array(
                    'answerId' = 1,
                    'answerText' = 'Answer string'
                ),
                array(
                    'answerId' = 2,
                    'answerText' = 'Answer string'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**edit**

My current implementation is as follows, what I wanted to do was eager load the data rather than perform so many queries

```
$tests = getTests();

foreach($tests as $test){

    $questions = getQuestions($test->id);

    foreach($questions as $question){

        $answers = getAnswers($question->id);

        foreach($answers as $answer){

            // do answer things

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: that would require the use of a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in my opinion maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


$query = "SELECT testname, question, answer
    FROM tests 
    JOIN questions ON (tests.id = question.test_id)
    JOIN answers ON (questions.id = answers.id)
    WHERE 'your condition'
    ORDER BY tests.id, question.id"

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

You can use in_array function to get your desired result (you can make array or print result). Here is an example of printing values. (you can use id instead of name for betterment)

```
$tests_arr = array();
$questions_arr = array();

while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
{
    if(!in_array($row['testname'], $test_arr)
    {
        $test_arr[] = $row['testname'];
        echo $row['testname'];
    }

    if(!in_array($result['question'], $question_arr))
    {
        $questions_arr[] = $row['question'];
        echo $row['question'];
    }

    echo $row['answer'];
}
```

Comment: As the [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions are no longer recommended for use, please do not recommend their usage in answers that the OP does not show they use them in. Instead, recommend usage of [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) methods.

Comment: Oh, thanks newfurniturey. Didn't knew that. Will change this to mysqli instead

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can't return an array structure in the format you desire - the best it can do is a 2D-array to represent the columns/rows.

Two alternatives would be both implemented in PHP.

1. Run a query for each test; iterate through each test and run a query to get all questions for this test; iterate through each question and run a query for the answers for this question.

Example:

```
// get each test
$tests = array();
$results = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, name FROM tests;');
while ($test = $results->fetch_object()) $tests[] = $test;
foreach ($tests as $t => $test) {
    // get all questions for this test
    $tests[$t]['questions'] = array();
    $results = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, name FROM questions WHERE test_id = ' . $test['id']);
    while ($question = $results->fetch_object()) $tests[$t]['questions'][] = $question;
    foreach ($tests[$t]['questions'] as $q => $question) {
        // get all answers for this question
        $tests[$t]['questions'][$q]['answers'] = array();
        $results = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, name FROM answers WHERE question_id = ' . $question['id']);
        while ($answer = $results->fetch_object()) $tests[$t]['questions'][$q][] = $answer;
    }
}
```

2. Run a single query using MySQL joins and pre-iterate through the list of results to build an array in the format you desire.

Answer (score 1):

In plain SQL you could do a join, but that would get you flattened rows, the number of rows would be tests * questions * answers. You'd then have to parse and map the properties to appropriate objects. Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tests t, questions q, answers a  WHERE q.t_id = t.id AND a.q_id = q.id";
$rows = // do your fetching, pdo, mysqli, whatever, just get the rows

$tests = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    // map test
    if(!isset($tests[$row['t_id']])) $tests[$row['t_id']] = array(
       // set test attributes here (without the questions)
    );

    // map question
    if(!isset($tests[$row['t_id']]['questions'][$row['q_id']])) = array(
       // set question attributes here (without the answers)
    );

    // map answer
    if(!isset($tests[$row['t_id']]['questions'][$row['q_id']]['answers'][$row['a_id']])) = array(
       // set answer attributes here 
    );
}
```

The $tests array should now have the hierarchy you required,
but be sure to test this, but even if it doesn't work, you get the idea.

Having said that, take a look at some ORM-s.
For one of the simplest (in a good way) take a look at this:
http://phpmaster.com/database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm/

The tutorial is quite easy to go through, and in the end you get just what you asked, a set of objects with properties and a nice hierarchy based on table relations.

Answer (score 0):

You would `LEFT JOIN` so that the results are something like:

```
test1|question1|answer1
test1|question1|answer2
test1|question2|answer1
test1|question2|answer2
test2|question1|answer1
```

Then you loop through it in such a way that they always come in that order, so write a loop that fetches a row, if the test has changed since the last one, move to the next test in the array. Repeat for question and finally add the answers.

Some pseudocode

```
fetcharray()
if test > lasttest
  arraytest++
  arrayquestion = 0
elif question > lastquestion
  arrayquestion++

array[arraytest][arrayquestion][] = fetched array
```